# oracle database meet delete error when having cascade and trigger together

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, cascade

I have two table in database,one is PS_POST and one is PS_STAR.

Here is there DDL:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table PS_POST
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "C##STY"."PS_POST" 
   (    "POST_ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE , 
    "USER_ID" NUMBER, 
    "GROUP_ID" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "TIME" DATE, 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) DEFAULT 'Default_title', 
    "STAR_NUMBER" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "CONTENT" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) DEFAULT 'Default_content'
   )  ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index POST_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "C##STY"."POST_PK" ON "C##STY"."PS_POST" ("POST_ID") ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table PS_POST
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "C##STY"."PS_POST" MODIFY ("USER_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "C##STY"."PS_POST" ADD CONSTRAINT "POST_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("POST_ID")
    ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "C##STY"."PS_POST" MODIFY ("POST_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);



--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table PS_STAR
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "C##STY"."PS_STAR" 
   (    "USER_ID" NUMBER, 
    "POST_ID" NUMBER, 
    "TIME" DATE
   ) ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index STAR_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "C##STY"."STAR_PK" ON "C##STY"."PS_STAR" ("USER_ID", "POST_ID") 
   ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Trigger STAR_TRIGGER
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "C##STY"."STAR_TRIGGER" after insert on PS_STAR
referencing new as new old as old 
for each row
begin
update PS_POST
set 
STAR_NUMBER = STAR_NUMBER + 1
where POST_ID = :new.POST_ID;

end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "C##STY"."STAR_TRIGGER" ENABLE;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Trigger STAR_DELETE_TRIGGER
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "C##STY"."STAR_DELETE_TRIGGER" before delete on PS_STAR
referencing new as new old as old 
for each row
begin
update PS_POST
set 
STAR_NUMBER = STAR_NUMBER - 1
where POST_ID = :old.POST_ID;

end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "C##STY"."STAR_DELETE_TRIGGER" ENABLE;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table PS_STAR
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "C##STY"."PS_STAR" ADD CONSTRAINT "STAR_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("USER_ID", "POST_ID")
   ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "C##STY"."PS_STAR" MODIFY ("POST_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "C##STY"."PS_STAR" MODIFY ("USER_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

So I set PS_STAR to be cascade deleted when a post is deleted. I also have a trigger to update STAR_NUMBER in PS_POST table when a star record is deleted.The problem occurs when I try to delete an item in PS_POST,it seems that the trigger in PS_STAR can not work properly and it gives me error:

```
ORA-04091: C##STY.PS_POST is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

How to solve this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cut a lot of irrelevant storage clauses etc, out of your DDL so we can read it more easily.  Now it appears thetre is no foreign key definition in there at all - I went back and checked, it wasn't there before my edit either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best plan would be to remove the **denormalised** STAR_NUMBER column from the PS_POST table and drop the triggers - you can just count the number of PS_STAR records when you need the number. "Denormalisation for performance" is rarely justified except in some extreme cases.

However if you really need to keep it, you need to prevent your triggers from trying to update the PS_POST table when a record is being deleted from it.  This can be achieved using a package with a global variable in it like this:

```
create or replace package ps_post_pkg is
  deleting_post boolean default false;
end;
```

Then add two **statement**-level triggers to PS_POST:

```
create or replace trigger ps_post_before_delete_stmt
before delete on ps_post
begin
  ps_post_pkg.deleting_post := true;
end;

create or replace trigger ps_post_after_delete_stmt
after delete on ps_post
begin
  ps_post_pkg.deleting_post := false;
end;
```

Now amend your START_DELETE_TRIGGER's body to:

```
begin
  if not ps_post_pkg.deleting_post then
    update PS_POST
    set STAR_NUMBER = STAR_NUMBER - 1
    where POST_ID = :old.POST_ID;
  end if;
end;
```

Now when a record is deleted from PO_POST, the delete will cascade to PS_STAR, but the START_DELETE_TRIGGER will not try to update the PS_POST record that was just deleted.